# Mezuzahs on home in probate

Tags: mezuzah, real-estate

If a Jewish person passes away intestate. Do the most probable heirs have an obligation to put up mezuzahs while the home is in probate?

Comment: Who lives in the home if the owner died?

Comment: Well theoretically nobody.

Comment: Then theoretically it would seem nobody is obligated to attach mezuzot

Comment: I was under the impression even if the property is jewish owned it would require it